# Different Log files for different package:Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging

I would like to log into multiple files based on logging levels ? Can it be achieved in Spring boot from application.properties like error logs in error.logs and debug.logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can log into multiple files based on different logging levels by modifying logback.xml file.
Define different appenders for multiple files and then define multiple loggers in logback.xml, associate each appender with each logger. Now when you change log level different files will write logs accordingly.

File Appender for INFO Log level.

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>./log/elk-file.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <!--cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart-->
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>./log/elk-file_%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>200MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>1</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{ISO8601} [%thread] %level{5} %c{3} - %message%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

File Appender for Error Log level.

```
<appender name="FILE_Err" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>./log/elk-file.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <!--cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart-->
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>./log/elk-file_%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>200MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>1</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{ISO8601} [%thread] %level{5} %c{3} - %message%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Now define Loggers for each file inside Logback.xml

```
<logger name="ro.fortsoft.elk.testdata" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>

<logger name="ro.fortsoft.elk.newName" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_Err"/>
</logger>
```

Now get Logger in class where you want to use it

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER1 = LoggerFactory.getLogger("<name of logger define in logback.xml>");
```

Logs will start appearing in different files accordingly.